# file_put_content() file permission error

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

On my code I am sending url encoded image and using file_out_content to turn it to a file.

```
    if(file_put_contents($arg['org_file'],$decodeData))
    {
        chmod($arg['org_file'],777);
        $arg = Model_Photo::_convert_png_to_jpg($arg);

        //reduce file
        \Fuel\Core\Image::load($arg['org_file'])
                ->config('quality',80)
                ->resize($arg['width'])
                ->save($arg['org_file'],755);
```

When my execution gets the code above. the part with the Image::Load I get this error.

```
Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Warning ]:
getimagesize(/www/my.website.com/public/uploads/2013-11-18/4511582301f8b92b08aad0b8e.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

You can see that I chmod the created file to 777, but looking at the console the permission is not 777.

```
--wxrw--wt 1 apache apache 291301 Nov 18 18:07 4511582301f8b92b08aad0b8e.jpg
```

The absence of read make it problematic for me to do file manipulation. I did the chmod but it is not working, so I think I am missing something. Kindly help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just `777` is not the same as the octal representation that *nix uses. You need to add the `0` prefix to indicate the number is meant to be octal.

```
chmod($arg['org_file'], 0777);
```

**Update**

The same goes for your call to `->save()`:

```
->save($arg['org_file'], 0755);
```

To illustrate:

```
777  = 1100001001 (01411)
0777 =  111111111
```

Comment: Sorry, it was working, then I relalized it was my local copy of the project. anyway, it is not working. No changes in the error indicated.

Comment: the ->save($arg['org_file'],755) is the culprit. Change it to 0777 and it's working. I will just change somethings. Thanks.

Comment: @MrA I didn't realize that the last argument of `->save()` was also a permission ... I'm glad my answer worked for both though :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `chmod($arg['org_file'],0777);`